# Problems listing block size

Tags: c, linux, recursion, block, diskspace

I'm currently working on a project dealing with block sizes for directories and files in linux.  Now I know how to find the blocksize and print it out, but I was wondering if there is a way to change the block size from 1024 to 512.  Im just wondering if there is a built in command to do this in linux.  Like chdir command.  If so let me know and reference the header file for man.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to re-format, I believe you are SOL.  Check `fdisk`.

Block size is often a characteristic of how data is organized within the media (e. g. hard drive) and would need a low level re-organization like re-formating the disk to the desired block size.  Variant blocks sizes may not even be allowed for various media.